# Factoring singular conics into linear forms

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for an easy way to factor singular conics into linear forms in order the following exercise.

> Which of the following quadratic forms define a singular > conic? Write those as a product of two linear forms.
>
> (a) $x_0^2-2x_0x_1+4x_0x_2-8x_1^2+2x_1x_2+3x_2^2$
>
> (b) $x_0^2-2x_0x_1+x_1^2-2x_0x_2$
>
> (c) $3x_0^2-2x_0x_1$

The matrices of (b) and (c) have full rank and so the quadratic forms are non-degenerate. For (a), we have the matrix

$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 \\
-1 & -8 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $det(M)=0$.
One way to solve the exercise would be to orthogonally diagonalize M to get rid of the mixed terms. However this involves computing the eigenvalues of M and finding the corresponding eigenvectors. So my question is: Is there a quicker way to do this or do I have to go through the calculations?

Comment: Please explain what are $x_0$, $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: $x_0, x_1 ,x_2$ are the coefficients of the vector $(x_0, x_1 ,x_2) \in R^3$

Comment: But is that a conic or a quadric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the roots of the polynomial with respect to one of the variables (e.g. $x_0$):
$$
x_0^2-2x_0(x_1-2x_2)-8x_1^2+2x_1x_2+3x_2^2=0
$$
giving:
$$
x_0=(x_1-2x_2)\pm\sqrt{(x_1-2x_2)^2+8x_1^2-2x_1x_2-3x_2^2}
=(x_1-2x_2)\pm(3x_1-x_2)=
\cases{4x_1-3x_2\cr-2x_1-x_2}.
$$
Hence, by the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) we have:
$$
x_0^2-2x_0x_1+4x_0x_2-8x_1^2+2x_1x_2+3x_2^2=(x_0-4x_1+3x_2)(x_0+2x_1+x_2).
$$